# translate by replacing words inside existing text

Tags: python, regex, language-agnostic, string, nlp

What are common approaches for translating certain words (or expressions) inside a given text, when the text must be reconstructed (with punctuations and everythin.) ?

The translation comes from a lookup table, and covers words, collocations, and emoticons like L33t, CUL8R, :-), etc.

Simple string search-and-replace is not enough since it can replace part of longer words (cat > dog  ≠>  caterpillar > dogerpillar).

Assume the following input:

```
s = "dogbert, started a dilbert dilbertion proces cat-bert :-)"
```

after translation, i should receive something like:

> result = "**anna**, started a **george** dilbertion **process** cat-bert **smiley**"

I can't simply tokenize, since i loose **punctuations** and **word positions**.

Regular expressions, works for normal words, but don't catch special expressions like the smiley :-) but it does .

```
re.sub(r'\bword\b','translation',s) ==> translation
re.sub(r'\b:-\)\b','smiley',s) ==> :-)
```

for now i'm using the above mentioned regex, and simple replace for the non-alphanumeric words, but it's far from being bulletproof.

(p.s. i'm using python)

Comment: ok. so do you know of a "school solution" for such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with standard emoticons to be replaced with values. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons) is a list of emoticons. I had them in a plain text file (so that I can append/delete to it as and when required) separated by tab like.

```
:[        -1
:/        -1
:(          -1
:)         1
```

Then read it into a dictionary

```
emoticons = {}          
for line in open('data/emoticons.txt').xreadlines():   
        symbol, value = line.split('\t')                                           
        emoticons[str(symbol)] = int(value)
```

Then a lookup function

```
def mark_emoticons(t):
    for w, v in emoticons.items():
        match = re.search(re.escape(w),t)
            if match:
                print w, "found "
```

Call the function with

```
mark_emoticons('Hello ladies! How are you? Fantastic :) Look at your man ...')
```

As for L33t-speak I have a separate file slangs.txt, which looks like

```
u   you
ur  you are
uw  you are welcome 
wb  welcome back 
wfm works for me 
wtf what the fuck
```

A similar function to read it to dictionary slangs{} and a similar function to replace the slangs.

```
def mark_slangs(t):        
    for w, v in slangs.items():
            s = r'\b' + w + r'\b'
            match = re.search(s,t)
            if match:
                    #print w, "found in:",t, "replacing with",readtable.slangs[w]
                    t = re.sub(w,slangs[w].rstrip(),t)
                    ...
```

From [Python library](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) the re.escape()

> re.escape(string) 
>   Return string with
>   all non-alphanumerics backslashed;
>   this is useful if you want to match an
>   arbitrary literal string that may have
>   regular expression metacharacters in
>   it.

Based on your needs you might want to use re.findall()

Comment: since then i created a complex algorithm that tokenizes a couple of times, and replaces bot hby string-replace nad by regex, and each category is being processed at a specific stage. and then i've quitted the job. 10x anyway

Answer (score 1):

The reason your smiley example doesn't work with regex is the \b refers to a word boundary.  Since there are no "word" characters in the smiley, there is no word boundary, so your expression doesn't match.  You could use lookaheads/lookbehinds to see if you are bounded by spaces, but to check against punctuation could be difficult considering your smileys are made of punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that regexp can't match smileys (which is simply not true :P), but rather how your regular expression for that smiley is made.

The word boundary `\b` is described as follows in the python documentation:

> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of Unicode alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore Unicode character. Note that formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice versa).

The problem now is that symbols like `:`, `-` and `)` are <s>itself word-boundaries, so they are especially</s> not words, and as such won't match with `\w`. As such the space before the smiley is not recognized as a word boundary (simply because no word is following).

So if you want to match smileys you can't use `\b` but have to check for white spaces or something instead.

Comment: To be more specific `:`, `-`, and `(` are NOT word-boundaries.  Rather, they are not word characters.  Therefore, the position BETWEEN one of these characters and a word character is the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a non-regex solution, then here is my idea. Here are the steps I would use.

Preparation:

- Create a dictionary linking the words
  to be replaced to their replacements.
- Create a ternary tree of the words to
  be replaced.

Searching and replacing:

1. Split up the words by the spaces using split(). I use the term word to refer to a group of letters that doesn't contain a space.
2. Iterate through all of the words

   1. Search for the word in the ternary tree - if a partial match is found, check that the rest of the word is punctuation (or at least not stuff that would make it not be a match).
   2. Replace the word using the dictionary look-up if it was found in the ternary tree

You can read about ternary search trees [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/184410528). There are ternary search tree python implementations, but you can make your own pretty simply. The main problem with this approach is if there is punctuation before the word (like a "), but that can be dealt with easily.